# Android style.xml - how to change checkbox label text color?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to style my app. I managed to change the colors of all widgets, **but the checkboxes**. I've read that the checkbox label android:textColor [is inherited](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox) from textView, but when I apply the style below the labels of checkboxes are still black.

How do I change checkbox label color via style.xml ?

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/MyGray</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/MyBlue</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/MyGray</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713829/change-checkbox-text-color-when-checked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36635925/7666442