# Change text color of check box in a list view

Tags: java, android-studio, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

So I have a list of checkboxes in a list array populated with various text and a custom checkmark that effectively shows when I click the specific item. However, I can't seem to change the text color of the text in the item that is checked. I want to change it to the same color as the checkmark. When I do click on the item and when the text color is set to the textColor code below, the text turns pink! which is not the color I want. It seems to be a default color. My question is then how do I change the textColor of the particular checkbox that I have checked that is embedded in a listview? I have searched on this website and others but I couldn't find an answer that could help me.

text color

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:textColor="@color/purple_color" />
</selector>
```

and purple checkmark:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

and list view in the activity:

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/myList"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and the individual list item:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/orientation_type"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@drawable/check_box_text_color_purple"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:button="@drawable/check_purple" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the array adapter:

```
public class orientation_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<orientation_item> {

    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;

    public orientation_adapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<orientation_item> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mResource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        String orientation = getItem(position).getOrientation();

        gender_item user_orientation = new gender_item(orientation);

        LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflator.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        //TextView orientation_type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.orientation_type);
        CheckBox orientation_type = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.orientation_type);

        orientation_type.setText(orientation);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

and the main activity:

```
ArrayList<orientation_item> list = new ArrayList<>();

 //items created and added here

 adapter = new orientation_adapter(ChooseOrientation.this, R.layout.orientation_unit, list);

        myList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713829/change-checkbox-text-color-when-checked will this help you..

Comment: I ended up solving the problem. Not really sure what was wrong though. That's a good post though that could be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up applying this to the android:textColor field in the individual component xml of the listview. This solved the problem but is similar to what I did before. Android seems to respond better when you use actual color codes instead of linking to colors.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="#000000"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#FF6C63FF"/> <!-- checked -->
    <item android:color="#ffffff"/> <!-- anything else -->
</selector>
```